# Vertically center constrained image in Bootstrap thumbnail

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), I'm trying to create a horizontally scrolling series of [thumbnails](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails) which allows for a scrollbar within the row that the thumbnails are displayed in, like so:

[image]

This gets me most of the way there, using this HTML:

```
<div class="row">Hello there</div>
<div class="row" style="overflow-x:scroll">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="thumbnail" style="width: 400px; height: 400px">
                <img src="http://i.minus.com/iucsUZfSM9v45.gif"/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="thumbnail" style="width: 400px; height: 400px">
                <img src="http://i.minus.com/iucsUZfSM9v45.gif"/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="thumbnail" style="width: 400px; height: 400px">
                <img src="http://i.minus.com/iucsUZfSM9v45.gif"/>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/54fgv/2/

The `overflow` CSS property works great, giving me the scrollbar for the container `div`.

The thumbnail `div` elements are going to be a fixed size, which is more than likely going to be smaller than the image.  In this case, the image is constrained to fit accordingly.  As you can see though, when the image is wider than the thumbnail, the width is set to the thumbnail and the height is scaled accordingly.  This is the behavior that I want, but I'd like to have the image vertically centered in the thumbnail.

I've tried adding `vertical-align: middle` to the thumbnail `div` elements, but to no avail.

How can I get the image to be centered vertically within the thumbnail?

Comment: @JoshCrozier No, because now the thumbnails are vertically constrained by the side of the row, which I don't want.  I very much want overflow on the horizontal axis.

Comment: Is [**this** better](http://jsfiddle.net/4MV3e/)?

Comment: @JoshCrozier Example 2, no because the image extends beyond the `height`/`width` constraint that I want, but example 1 looks to be exactly what I want.  I'm going to try it soon.

Comment: @JoshCrozier Although the rounded corners of the thumbnail are now gone.

Comment: Alright, `border-collapse: separate` seems to fix that [**updated example**](http://jsfiddle.net/cnPzP/).. take a look at this [**alternative example**](http://jsfiddle.net/eQbj6/) too.. it doesn't require the wrapper element, however it does have [slightly less support](http://caniuse.com/flexbox)..

Comment: I am assuming this is a simplified example, but what is the point in using the grid if you're not going to use columns (ie `col-xs-{number}`)? The table is acting as columns which entirely defeats the purpose. Am I missing something?

Comment: @CarrieKendall Using the grid doesn't allow for the overflow of the content; the section above this one will be constrained by the grid, while the bottom will allow for overflow that is scrollable to see.

Comment: Are you opposed to a grid (with columns) solution?

Comment: @CarrieKendall I'm using Bootstrap, so all of the other content is a grid with columns solution.  It's this one particular section which I want to overflow.  If there is a way to achieve that with grids and columns, then so be it, but most grid systems actively work to *prevent* overflow, which I specifically want in this case.

Comment: [challenge accepted](http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/500x/45536123.jpg)

Comment: does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mffox/L8GmN/3/) do what you want?

Comment: the img height is wacky in ff, but since you've found a solution I'm not going to debug :) maybe the idea will inspire future visitors?

Comment: @CarrieKendall I haven't tested the solution in FF, but yours looks great as well, thank you.

Comment: I'll post as an answer later when I have time to polish it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Approach 1** - [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/pLTsy/):

Wrap the `img` elements:

```
<div class="thumbnail" style="width: 400px; height: 400px">
    <div class="thumbnail_wrapper">
        <img src="http://i.minus.com/iucsUZfSM9v45.gif"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Change the display of the `.thumbnail` element to `table`. Use `border-collapse: separate` to fix padding/spacing issues. Change the display of the wrapper to `table-cell` and then add `vertical-align: middle`. Finally, give the `img` elements a width of `100%`.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/pLTsy/)

```
.thumbnail {
    display:table;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-radius:10px; /* Demonstrational.. */
}
.thumbnail_wrapper {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.thumbnail_wrapper > img {
    width:100%;
}
```

---

**Approach 2** - [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/FPtBS/):

The flexbox approach doesn't require the wrapper element, however it has [slightly less support](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) than the `table`/`table-cell` approach.

```
<div class="thumbnail" style="width: 400px; height: 400px">
    <img src="http://i.minus.com/iucsUZfSM9v45.gif" />
</div>
```

Basically, just change the `display` of the `.thumbnail` element to `flex` and then add `align-items: center`. All the other vendor prefixes are added for cross browser support. Read more about flexbox layouts and properties [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) - (mdn).

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/FPtBS/)

```
.thumbnail {
    display: -webkit-flexbox;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

---

As a side note, you can avoid having to use HTML tables - [**example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/WGZ3Z/).

Comment: Note, the HTML tables example doesn't work as the image expands to full width, and is not constrained to 400 px, but the rest looks very good.  Also, I've been able to clean up example 1 to use use Bootstrap's rounded corners, as well as remove applying overflow to the body element: http://jsfiddle.net/pLTsy/1/

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="thumbnail v_align_all" style="width: 400px; height: 400px">
    <img src="http://i.minus.com/iucsUZfSM9v45.gif"/>
    <span class="v_align_fix"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.v_align_all { white-space: nowrap }

.v_align_all > * {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block !important;
}

.v_align_fix {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```