# Vertically Center an Image inside a div in CSS and Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrapped HTML/ CSS. I need to vertically center an image inside a Bootstrap grid.

On lowering the screen size, the image tends to go upwards. 
Like [this](http://prntscr.com/4p3r1h). I need the image to always be vertically centered ( Drawn in Red box)

The fiddle for the issue is [here](http://www.bootply.com/IRB8QtYZas).

What change should be made in the CSS that image is always vertically centered in the responsive bootstrap grid?

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477909/vertically-center-constrained-image-in-bootstrap-thumbnail) may be helpful.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771101/centering-a-button-vertically-in-table-cell-using-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: @JoshCrozier : I've tried vertical align, It still doesnt work.

Comment: @DanielCheung: Vertical Align seems to make no difference.

Comment: @Tom Sarduy: Could you help please?